# WPF c# - Execute a task continuously and allow execution of another task

Tags: c#, multithreading, concurrency

I am running a macro via c# using the procedure:

**TASK 1 :**

```
 EXCELApplicationObj.GetType().InvokeMember("Run",
       System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Default |
       System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod,
       null, EXCELApplicationObj, oRunArgs);
```

But while this function is going on i want to check the occurence of a window by its titlename and for that i used this:

**TASK 2 :**

```
Process[] processlist = Process.GetProcesses();
foreach (Process process in processlist)
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(process.MainWindowTitle))
    {
        process.ProcessName, process.Id, process.MainWindowTitle);
        if (process.MainWindowTitle == "Untitled - Notepad") {
            process.Kill();
        }
    }
}
```

But the issue is i want to run this parrallel in the process so that i want to execute the macro and whernever the new window appears named "Untitled - Notepad" i want to close it. 
Can any stackoverflowers can give me any guidance on this.
Heard of threading but i dont know much about threading..

Update:
What iam looking for:

**Perform Task2 continuosly and to allow execution of Task1.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example to automatically close a window in parallel while running some code:

```
static void Main() {

    // execute AsyncCloseTopWindow in parallel to close a window named "Untitled - Notepad"
    var thread = new Thread(AsyncCloseTopWindow);
    thread.IsBackground = true;          
    thread.Start("Untitled - Notepad");

    // execute the macro while AsyncCloseTopWindow is running 
    //...

    // exit AsyncCloseTopWindow
    thread.Interrupt();
}

private static void AsyncCloseTopWindow(object windowTitle) {
    try {
        while (true) {

            // close any window matching the title
            IntPtr hwnd = FindWindow(IntPtr.Zero, (string)windowTitle);
            if (!hwnd.Equals(IntPtr.Zero)) {
                SendMessage(hwnd, WM_CLOSE, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
            }

            // wait 30ms
            Thread.Sleep(30);
        }
    } catch (ThreadInterruptedException) { }
}

private const UInt32 WM_CLOSE = 0x0010;

[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
private static extern IntPtr FindWindow(IntPtr lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
```

Comment: Hi @Florent B. , any idea how to use DllImport in wpf, it is showing erro.

Comment: Error 4 The type or namespace name 'DllImport' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Comment: i think it will be taken in c# winfroms but not in wpf

Comment: I've just tested it a new WPF app. It works as expected. The full signature is `System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport`. Note that the `DllImport` it need to be placed in a class

Comment: Thank you so much... i have been carrying this issue for a while... thanks a lot...

Answer (score 1):

You can use a separate thread to run the code on that looks for the windows and closes them. You need a private field `stopClosingWindows` in the object to tell the parallel Thread when to terminate.

private bool stopClosingWindows;

You need a separate method to perform the action of looking for windows and closing them in a loop:

```
private void ParallelCloseWindows()
{
    while (!stopClosingWindows)
    {
        // Only look every 200ms so we don't waste processor ressources
        Thread.Sleep(200);

        // perform the task
        Process[] processlist = Process.GetProcesses();
        foreach (Process process in processlist)
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(process.MainWindowTitle))
            {
                if (process.MainWindowTitle == "Untitled - Notepad")
                {
                    process.Kill();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now before you start your actual code executing the macro, set `stopClosingWindows` to false and start the parallel thread. And after your actual code executing the macro, set `stopClosingWindows` to false to signal the thread it can stop and terminate.

Use try/finally so that the parallel thread stops even when there is an exception while executing the macro.

```
stopClosingWindows = false;
try
{
    // Create a new thread that should execute the method ParallelCloseWindows in parallel
    var thread = new Thread(ParallelCloseWindows);

    // set isBackground to true so that this thread would not prevent your application from closing when 
    // we forget to terminate it
    thread.IsBackground = true;

    // and start the new thread
    thread.Start();

    EXCELApplicationObj.GetType().InvokeMember("Run", 
            System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Default 
            | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod,
            null, EXCELApplicationObj, oRunArgs);
}
finally
{
    stopClosingWindows = true;
}
```

Comment: thank you @NineBerry ... but when i tried iam getting an exception at the macro invoaction line... any idea!

Comment: `An unhandled exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll Additional information: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.`

Comment: I'd say the error occurs in the macro when the macro tries to do something with the notepad window it has created. Seems like you cannot simply close the notepad instances. Maybe close them all after the macro has finished execution?

Comment: Thanks NineBerry, but the macro exits only if you close that Notepad... otherwise i have to manually close it..

Answer (score 1):

I take it you wish to run the "kill all untitled notepad processes" in a loop. With that in mind, try this ...

```
public void killNotepad()
    {
        Process[] processlist = Process.GetProcesses();
        foreach (Process process in processlist)
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(process.MainWindowTitle))
            {
                //process.ProcessName, process.Id, process.MainWindowTitle);
                if (process.MainWindowTitle == "Untitled - Notepad")
                {
                    process.Kill();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void killNotepadRunAsync()
    {
        System.Threading.Thread th = new System.Threading.Thread(() =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                killNotepad();
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(300);
            }
        });
        th.SetApartmentState(System.Threading.ApartmentState.STA);
        th.Start();
    }
```

The "killNotepad()" method is run multiple times in a thread executed by the "killNotepadRunAsync()" method, so call the killNotepadRunAsync() method where you need it.

The System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(300) makes the thread sleep for 300 milliseconds before it makes the next Process.getProcesses() call, which gives your cpu some time to catch its breath.

Umm, i commented out the eigth line, cos i wasn't sure what you wished to do with it. It was also a syntax error.

Have fun with threads!

Comment: my macro invocation is shwoing an exception which says : `An unhandled exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.`